# Mosfet or bjt choice for low voltage joule thief application

Tags: transistors, solar-cell, low-power, energy, joule-thief

I make solar energy harvester using joule thief circuit with a small solar cell as the input. The output voltage from the solar cell is 0,5V. But the generic transistor, exactly silicon material need for 0,7V to start conducting.

Is there any transistor type (mosfet or bjt) that work with 0,5V or lower for my project ?

Thanks you,

Answer (score 4):

Indeed 0.5 V is too small to do anything useful with a BJT.

For MOSFETs the threshold voltage \$V_t\$ matters, the ones with the lowest \$V_t\$ I can find have \$V_t\$ between 0.3 V and 1.0 V, for example the [Si2334DS](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2050299.pdf).

That 0.3 V sounds good **however** that is the minimum value, the manufacturer guarantees that \$V_t\$ is always 0.3 V or higher (but less than 1.0 V). This does not mean that you can buy a MOSFET which has a \$V_t\$ of 0.3 V. Typically the \$V_t\$ will be around 0.65 V I guess, so that will not be more usable than a BJT.

There are solutions which can work on a voltage of 0.5 V but these use a dedicated power harvesting IC, for example the [BQ25570](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq25570.pdf) but do not that even this IC needs at least 0.6 V to **start up**. Once started it can work down to 0.1 V at its input.

Do note that a BQ25570 solution is **significantly** more complex than your "Joule thief" idea.

You really need a bit more voltage 0.5 V to do anything useful at all. Can't you use two solar panels in series?

Comment: There are other integrated solutions that have ultralow startup voltage. For example LTC3108. From datasheet: *minimum startup voltage 50mV*, but it uses some fancy transformer and I don't even understand how this works (but I'm sure it does work, if engineers from LT said so).

Comment: The threshold voltage of a mosfet is almost entirely arbitrary and can even be trimmed to an extent by the end user. But it’s best to leave that to the manufacturer. You can buy mosfets with very closely controlled threshold voltages that can be positive, zero, or even negative. They cost more, but you get IMHO good value for the money. They are specifically processed for that though, and they allow very low voltage logic, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can try germanium BJTs.

For example, I made joule thief with МП26Б PNP transistor. It lights up LED with input voltage of 0.2V. But, most likely, voltage can go down even to 0.1V.

Comment: A solar garden light uses an IC (an example is a QX5252F) that works from a Ni-MH battery cell that has a 0.9 minimum voltage. The solar panel is usually 2V (4 cells).

Comment: An alternative to a germanium transistor is a separate voltage source for the power to the L2+1K+NPN-Base. A guy named Rusty Bolt (or Watson A. Name) uses a fresh AAA, which is more than enough voltage. And because so little power is used, the AAA can last a very long time. And also go down to really low voltages. Also, replacing the 1K with 22 ohms + a 10K potentiometer allows brightness adjustment, and therefore increased run time. It is surprising how little light is necessary to read important books at night -- 2.6mA for me. STEM, STEAM, and STREAM!

Answer (score 0):

The Depletion Mode MOSFET works down to 0V, and should make an especially good low voltage Joule Thief.

The [N-Channel MOSFET IXTH16N20D2](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/ixys/IXTH16N20D2/2505036) has an especially low resistance, which is 73mOhm @ 8A, 0V.  (Low resistance compared to a BJT).

These can be expensive though -- the above one is $20.27 at Digikey as of Feb. 2024. This is probably why I haven't tried one yet. Might be justified for an energy harvesting application, though.

If we run some crowd funding, or group buy, campaigns, we can increase the use of these transistors -- also getting them at a better price.

But I should probably buy a cheaper one just to prove the idea first. Other parts of the energy harvesting solution may also be expensive, which is fine for a company to shoulder, but hard sometimes for enthusiasts to justify.

The IXTH16N20D2 would create a kick-butt Joule-Thief, though, as its max dissipation is 695 Watts!

---

Quick proof of concept: (this simulation is actually working. Uses 9V in).

The following working simulation should convert directly to the same circuit using a very low voltage depletion mode N-Channel MOSFET, into one LED.

[image]